# Haskell monad return type

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I'm trying to do a bit of programming and I can't get into monads. I've advanced a bit with IO functions, but now I'm definitely lost...

I've got a XML string that was loaded from the network (so it's "stored" in `IO String`). Because of this, I need a `do` block to load to common String.

```
foo :: IO String -> Nothing
foo xmlio = do
    xmlio <- xml
    -- do some magic
```

I've already implemented another function that takes pure string and returns pure XML element. It does a bit more, but let's simplify that as it's not important for this question.

```
import Text.XML.Light
import Text.XML.Light.Input

toxml :: String -> Maybe Element
toxml s = parseXMLDoc s
```

Now I tried to combine these two to accept an IO String and to return an "IO Element".

```
toxmlio :: IO String -> ??? Maybe Element
toxmlio s = do
    pures <- s
    let toReturn = parseXMLDoc s
    return s
```

The return function's type is (according to ghci) :

```
let foo = "<foo>bar</foo>"
:t return (parseXMLDoc foo)
    >> return (parseXMLDoc foo) :: Monad m => m (Maybe Element)
```

But if I change the header of my function to

```
toxmlio :: IO String -> Monad (Maybe Element)
toxmlio s = do
    pures <- s
    let toReturn = parseXMLDoc s
    return s
```

I get a compilation error

```
Kind mis-match
The first argument of `Monad' should have kind `* -> *',
but `Maybe Element' has kind `*'
In the type signature for `xmlio':
  xmlio :: String -> Monad (Maybe Element)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue? Or am I completely lost and haskell does this another way? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Defining a function that takes an `IO String` argument is the wrong thing to do here. An `IO String` is not a string wrapped in some stuff, it's a _procedure_ which returns a string. For example, binding it twice will load it from the network twice. You don't usually write functions that take `IO something` as an argument unless you're writing some kind of control structure. I think it's better if you ask for help writing the code you want to call this from instead.

Comment: I'm really just a beginner in Haskell and to be honest, I don't like its laziness. 
I know about the function-like behaviour. I don't like to be very specific about the topic, basically I need to load an XML from the Internet, process it and based on the results I'll load another XML. 
However, I do want to split the tasks into more functions and therefore I wanted to implement these methods using IO input (since the most insider function returns IO and I can't get rid of it). So, is it better to have a single `do` that processes the input, wraps the IO and calls the other functions normally?

Comment: Yes. Keep as much of your code pure as possible. It's both easier to work with and understand and it also makes it easier to test your functions in an interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
toxmlio :: IO String -> IO (Maybe Element)
toxmlio s = do
    pures <- s
    let toReturn = parseXMLDoc pures
    return toReturn
```

however you can use `liftM`:

```
toxmlio :: IO String -> IO (Maybe Element)
toxmlio = liftM parseXMLDoc
```

You could make it even more general, since `liftM` does not depend on a particular monad type:

```
toxmlio :: Monad m => m String -> m (Maybe Element)
toxmlio = liftM parseXMLDoc
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this solution works, but I'll rather follow hammar's recommendations. I'm accepting this answer anyway.