# How to use value from different type monad in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, monads

Honestly, I feel like this must have a dupe somewhere, but I couldn't find [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314789/how-to-take-out-a-value-out-of-a-monad-in-haskell) [even](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553439/haskell-monad-return-type) [after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306846/getting-values-out-of-io-monad) [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568771/get-value-from-io-rather-than-the-computation-itself) [.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567743/how-to-extract-value-from-monadic-action)

Say I have the following code to simply get read a double from the user and echo it back:

```hs
import qualified Control.Monad.Except as E
import Text.Read(readMaybe) 

data Error = ParseError String
             | Default String deriving (Show)

type ThrowsError = Either Error 

main = do
  putStrLn "Enter your number: "
  val <- getDouble
  print val

parseString :: String -> ThrowsError Double
parseString val = maybe (E.throwError $ ParseError val) return 
                        (readMaybe val :: Maybe Double)

getDouble :: ThrowsError Double
getDouble = getLine >>= parseString
```

This breaks in two places:

1. In `main`, `putStrLn` is type `IO Double` but `getDouble` is type `ThrowsError Double`.
2. In `getDouble`, `getLine` is type `IO Double` but `parseString` returns `IO Double`.

Essentially, I'd want to be able to extract the value out of the `IO` monad, apply computations on it, and put it back inside the appropriate monad. However, the bind function seems to expect the same monad types for input and output, so what I want to do doesn't work.

What's the way around it?

Comment: The thing is, you can't just unwrap an arbitrary monad. So what you do instead is stack monads together with monad transformers. You need something like `type ThrowsError m = ExceptT Error m` and `getDouble :: ThrowsError IO Double`, and put `lift` in appropriate places

Comment: It's always the other way around: With monad you cannot freely extract values. But you can lift your operation into the context of the monad. Lifting is the functor operation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need any transformers.  `parseString` is a pure function, so to apply it to a monadic action you use `fmap` (aka `(<$>)`), not `(>>=)` as you have.

```
getDouble :: IO (ThrowsError Double)
getDouble = parseString <$> getLine
```

You would use `(>>=)` if `parseString` returned an `IO something`.

Comment: Ah, just `fmap` to apply within the Monad. Thank you!